# hide header on a stackNavigator screen that is inside DrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a stackNavigator (with 2 screens - Home and Details) inside DrawerNavigator,the stackNavigator is a option in the DrawerNavigator.
how can I hide the header only in the DetailsScreen ?
I tried put props headerShown:false, but doesn't work
this is my code.

I'm a little new with this.

```
export const MenuLateral = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <MenuInterno {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="HomeNavigation"
        component={HomeNavigation}
        options={{title: 'Home'}}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="UserProfileScreen"
        component={UserProfileScreen}
        options={{title: 'My profile'}}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

const MenuInterno = ({navigation}: any) => {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView>
      {/* Parte del avatar */}
      <View>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'https://medgoldresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/avatar-placeholder.gif',
            width: 280,
            height: 120,
          }}
        />
      </View>

      {/* Opciones de menú */}
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={style.flexRow}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeNavigation')}>
          <Text> Home Screen</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={style.flexRow}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UserProfileScreen')}>
          <Text> Profile</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
};
```

```
export type RootStackParams = {
  HomeScreen: undefined; //Si no  recibe nada como parametro se envia undefined
  DetailScreen: any;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParams>();

export const HomeNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false, title: 'Home'}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DetailScreen"
        component={DetailScreen}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on my device and it's working [snack link](https://snack.expo.dev/@wmt_rn_asmeetarathod/lonely-stroopwafel)

**EDITED**
You may try this

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: true, title: 'Home' }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DetailScreen"
        component={DetailScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
```

Comment: Hi, I mean that in homeScreen it's ok see the header,  but when I go to the details screnn I expect don't see that header

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer, You can try this.